# Accessing dynamic id's created with Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am creating a dynamic form using the ng-repeat directive and create an input with an id called 'value' like this:

```
<input name="value" id="{{ 'value-' + $index }}" required>
```

And I am trying to perform form validation on the dynamic id (ie: value-0, value-1, ...) here with no avail:

```
<div ng-messages="form.{{ 'value-' + $index }}.$error">
     <div ng-message="required">This Is Required!</div>
</div>
```

Was wondering what the syntax would look like inside that ng-messages directive. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use property accessor in AngularJS expressions:

```
<input name="value-{{$index}}" id="{{ 'value-' + $index }}" required />
```

```
<div ng-messages="form['value-' + $index].$error">
     <div ng-message="required">This Is Required!</div>
</div>
```